# A Least Favourable Distribution theorem. Why the extra condition.

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

One of the conclusions of theorem 5.3.8 is that the prior distribution $\pi$ is least favourable. Why is the extra condition $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0}E_{\theta}(L(\theta,\phi_{\pi}))\leq \alpha$ needed? Doesn't the Neyman-Person Lemma guarantee it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: is it just me or half of the theorem is cropped out?

Comment: @tibL yes, you're right. I'll correct that.

Comment: Isn't there a typo? It seems like the definition should say that it minimises the power. E.g. suppose $\Theta_0=[-1,1]$, $\theta_1=2$. According to the given definition, the LFD would have all its mass on $-1$, whereas in this case the LFD clearly actually has all its mass on $1$. Given this typo, the source of your confusion is probably gone (i.e. the difference between maximising power for a specific $\pi$ and maximising power for all $\pi$).

Comment: @cfp Thanks for the comment... ;)